# Addiction ou dépendance ?

Tags: néologismes, standard, anglicismes

Depuis quelques années, le mot *addiction* est employé de plus en plus souvent, en particulier dans le style journalistique, pour parler de dépendances. Cependant je n'ai trouvé de traces ni dans le TLF ni dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie.

Dans quelle mesure cet emploi est-il standard ?

Comment: J'ai plusieurs fois entendu le terme [*assuétude*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/assu%C3%A9tude) (employé par certains de la profession) avec ce sens là, bien qu'il ne désigne pas nécessairement une dépendance forte.

Comment: +1, pour avoir posé une question qui me tracassait. Formé à la `dépendance` francophone, la récente `addiction` anglo-saxonne énerve mes tympans ancien modèle. Ainsi vont les langues.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Alors qu'il n'apparait pas dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie, un [article](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addiction) Wikipédia y est consacré. La partie étymologie est intéressante (voir l'article pour la version complète) :

> Le terme addiction est d'étymologie latine, *ad-dicere* « dire à ». Dans la civilisation romaine, les esclaves n'avaient pas de nom propre et étaient *dits* à leur Pater familias. L'addiction exprime une absence d'indépendance et de liberté, un esclavage. [...]
>
> Toujours en langue anglaise, le mot addiction est totalement intégré dans le langage populaire pour désigner toutes les passions dévorantes et les dépendances par exemple : c'est un *sex-addict*. C'est cette popularité du terme chez les anglo-saxons qui explique son ambiguïté : les psychiatres anglophones hésitent souvent à l'utiliser (il a été retiré du DSM-IV¹, au profit du terme de « dépendance »).

Un autre paragraphe est particulièrement pertinent en ce qui concerne la question courante : [Addiction vs. dépendance](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addiction#Addiction_vs._d.C3.A9pendance). On apprend qu'il existe une nuance que je laisse l'article expliquer (voir à nouveau l'article pour la version complète) :

> Bien que le terme addiction soit souvent utilisé comme synonyme de dépendance, il existe en réalité une nuance entre ces deux concepts. [...]
>
> En pratique spécialisée, **la tendance consiste à utiliser le terme d'addiction pour ne désigner que le volet comportemental du phénomène de dépendance** (Lusher et al. Clin J Pain 2006).
> Cette nuance permet, par exemple, de distinguer les situation problématiques réelles lors de traitements médicamenteux prolongés par certains médicaments addictogènes.

Il semblerait donc que, bien qu'absent du dictionnaire de l'Académie, le français réutilise le mot anglais (venant du latin). Apparemment utilisé au début dans des contextes médicaux, il a rejoint le langage courant (ou du moins journalistique, les journalistes aimant bien utiliser le jargon des différents métiers).

—
<sub>1. DSM = Manuel diagnostique et statistique des troubles mentaux</sub>

Answer (score 3):

Les mots *accoutumance* et *dépendance* faisaient l'affaire ;

L'addiction est un ajout anglo-saxon comme on en voit partout, il n'ajoute rien et maintenant cache les deux autres mots que l'on voit de moins en moins.

Comment: Voir aussi la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=addiction&id=5311).